# Rename certain values of a row in a certain column if the meet the criteria

Tags: dataframe

How can I rename certain values of a row from a column if they meet a certain if-statement?

Example:

```
    Date    Type   C1 
    2000    none    3
    2000    love    4
    2000    none    6
    2000    none    2
    2000    bad     8
```

So I want to rename "love" and "bad" in my column type into "xxx".

```
    Date    Type   C1 
    2000    none    3
    2000    xxx     4
    2000    none    6
    2000    none    2
    2000    xxx     8
```

Is there a neat way of doing it?

Thank you :)

Comment: if you are using data.table, you can do: `df[Type %in% c('love','bad), Type := 'xxx']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure it's not a factor, then rename:

```
df$Type = as.character(df$Type)
df$Type[df$Type %in% c("love", "bad")] = "xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is a factor, you want to rename the factor level.  The easiest way to do that is with `fct_recode()` in the `forcats` package.  If it's a character vector, `ifelse` works well if the number of changes is small.  If it's large, `case_when` in the `dplyr` package works well.

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

df <- within(df, { # if you use `dplyr`, you can replace this with mutate.  You'd also need to change `<-` to `=` and add `,` at the end of each line.  
  Type_fct1 <- fct_recode(Type, xxx = "love", xxx = "bad")
  # in base R, you need can change the factor labels, but its clunky
  Type_fct2 <- Type
  levels(Type_fct2)[levels(Type_fct2) %in% c("love", "bad")] <- "xxx"

  # methods using character vectors
  Type_chr1 <- ifelse(as.character(Type) %in% c("love", "bad"), "xxx", as.character(Type))
  Type_chr2 <- case_when(
    Type %in% c("love", "bad") ~ "xxx",
    Type == "none" ~ "something_else", # thrown in to show how to use `case_when` with many different criterion.
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )

})
```